# Iterate through a one-to-many key-value jinja dictionary in SaltStack

Tags: dictionary, jinja2, salt-stack

I'm using a jinja one-to-many key-value dictionary in a SaltStack state:

```
{% for key in {'bash history': ['bash_history-backup.sh', 'History backup'],
                  'empty trash': ['delete-trash-files.sh', 'Delete trash files'],
                  'keepass backup': ['keepass-backup.sh', 'Backup KeePass'],
                  'db backup': ['mysql-backup.sh', 'Backup MySQL']} %}
{{ [key][0] }}:
  cron.present:
    - name: /home/vplagov/scripts/{{ [key][0] }}
    - user: vplagov
    - minute: 20
    - hour: 1
    - comment: 
    - require:
      - git: checkout latest bash_history backup
{% endfor %}
```

What I want to implement is to iterate not only through keys in this dictionary but through values assigned to this key as well. For example, use first value in `name`, second in `comment` and so on. Currently, I've managed to iterate through keys using `[key][0]` statement as shown above.

Do I need to use a second loop inside to iterate through values for each of a key? And how can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set an items variable?

```
from jinja2 import Template
tmpl = """
{% set items = {'bash history': ['bash_history-backup.sh', 'History backup'],
                  'empty trash': ['delete-trash-files.sh', 'Delete trash files'],
                  'keepass backup': ['keepass-backup.sh', 'Backup KeePass'],
                  'db backup': ['mysql-backup.sh', 'Backup MySQL']} %}
{% for key in items %}
{{ [key][0] }}:
  cron.present:
    - name: /home/vplagov/scripts/{{ items[key][0] }}
    - user: vplagov
    - minute: 20
    - hour: 1
    - comment: {{items[key][1]}}
    - require:
      - git: checkout latest bash_history backup
{% endfor %}
"""

template = Template(tmpl)
print(template.render())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That worked. But I don't really understand how do `[key][0]` and `items[key][0]` work? I mean, why in the first declaration you didn't use the variable name and used it in a second and third declaration?

Answer (score 3):

Taken literally, you can do something like this:

```
{%- set cronjobs = {'key1': [val1, val2], 'key2': [val1, val2]} %}
{%- for key, values in cronjobs.items() %}
{{ values[0] }}:
  cron.present:
    - name: /home/vplagov/scripts/{{ values[0] }}
    - comment: {{ values[1] }}
    # fixed values here...
{%- endfor %}
```

But if your example is close to your actual use case, I think you only need a flat dict. See if this suits your needs better:

```
{%- load_yaml as cronjobs %}
bash-history-backup.sh: History backup
delete-trash-files.sh: Delete trash files
keepass-backup.sh: Backup keepass
# ...more here...
{%- endload %}

{%- for script, comment in cronjobs.items() %}
cronjob-{{ script }}:
  cron.present:
    - name: /home/vplagov/scripts/{{ script }}
    - comment: {{ comment }}
    - minute: 20
    # etc
{%- endfor %}
```